# Unity Text object not visible outside canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I create an empty game object, add text module to it with random text, text will not be visible in editor regardness of the color , size or font.

When i place it as child under canvas, it appears normally

As i would like to create text element in prefabs, this is quite critical for me to find out the root cause.

My canvas are active, in Layer UI
Render Mode Screen Space - overlay
pixel perfect not ticked
sort order 0

target display display 1

Scale with screen size 1920 1080

Screen match mode match width or height

reference pixels per unit

Graphic raycaster

ignore reveresd graphics

blocking objects none

blocking mask everything

I also has 1 script making sure the camera following the character

Any club on why or anything i missed?

I do change the layer of the text object nothing happens as well

Everything is in 2D and no other gameobject present when i creating text, it show normally when under canvas. No shown when outside of it.

Comment: That's pretty much the expected behavior ... without a `Canvas` the `CanvasRenderer` is not being rendered ... You are probably looking for [`TextMeshPro`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/TMPObject3DText.html) instead

Comment: Or you need a canvas for each one

Comment: Thanks for the info, will TMP able to show text while being not as child object of Canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a WorldSpace Canvas object and place your game object with text component on it under the WorldSpace Canvas.

UI components are not visible outside Canvases. Like @derHugo said in the comments. If you want to display UI elements in the world like on top of a character or on a wall etc. You need to create a WorldSpace Canvas.

Comment: If i want to put text object in prefab, what should be the appoach? As prefab are not yet spawn in the begining of the game, is there anyway to put text component into prefab? e.g. Store image where Text will be the store name

Comment: If you're going to put the prefab under a `Canvas` component -If it's a UI element- then it's ok to create `a game object with text component without Canvas component.` As soon as you instantiate or placed the prefab under Canvas it should works fine.


But if you're going to use the prefab in `world space` then you need to create a WorldSpace Canvas component inside a prefab and then put the text component under it. Be sure that scene has only one `EventSystem`. Do not create `EventSystem` for each prefab/worldSpaceCanvas object.